Merging 2 Konsole windows in one (so each window is a tab in one window)
Is it possible to do in KDE Konsole? If yes, how?
If it's not possible in Konsole, are there any terminal emulators with this feature?
I tried drag&dropping a tab from one window to another (as suggested by an answer in this post possible to join/attach Konsole windows?), but tabs seems to be bonded to one window and can't be dragged out of it if there is only one tab, with two or more tabs dragged out tab just opens as a new window. "Run all Konsole windows as one process" turned on and all windows were reopened
